# How to import data from a CVS file into a existing field of a mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table `mileage_registrants` which keeps users registration data. It has a field `department` which is `NULL` for all users now.

The most difficult thing is that I need to do an automatic record match according to `user_id` and insert their department info from a `.csv` file into table `department`. There are one thousand records so it is horrible for me to insert them by hand.

Is there anyway for me to get this done quickly?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293783/how-do-i-import-this-data-file-to-a-mysql-table?

Comment: Do you mean CSV, not CVS?  Also, what scripting languages are at your disposal on the OS?  That _might_ make things easier (you might not have such options, but I thought it worth asking).

Answer (score 0):

The easiesit is to use phpMyAdmin to import the CSV file, that will create a dummy table like `TABLE 45` and from there you add some indexes, and you will write an update query that will join to the real table and update the relevant columns.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you give more details like an example. thanks